# I've created a recipe program for GCSE Computing, but I am missing one step

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, python-3.4, file-handling

This is my first post here and I am quite unsure on how to implement a vital piece of code in my coursework. I have created a very crude and basic recipe program on Python 3.4. Below is the piece I am missing.

• The program should ask the user to input the number of people.

• The program should output:

• the recipe name

• the new number of people

• the revised quantities with units for this number of people.

I am a complete beginner to programming and our teacher hasn't been very helpful and only explained the basics of file handling which I have attempted to implement into this program.

I will attach the code I have so far, but I would really appreciate some tips or an explanation on how I could implement this into my code and finally finish this task off as it is becoming very irksome.

Thank you!

**Code:**

I apologise if the code is cluttered or doesn't make sense. I am a complete novice.

```
      #!/usr/bin/env python

import time

def start():

    while True:
        User_input = input("\nWhat would you like to do? " "\n 1) - Enter N to enter a new recipe. \n 2 - Enter V to view an exisiting recipe, \n 3 - Enter E - to edit a recipe to your liking. \n 4 - Or enter quit to halt the program " "\n ")

        if User_input == "N":
            print("\nOkay, it looks like you want to create a new recipe. Give me a moment..." "\n")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            new_recipe()

        elif User_input == "V":
            print("\nOkay, Let's proceed to let you view an existing recipe stored on the computer")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            exist_recipe()

        elif User_input == "E":
            print("\nOkay, it looks like you want to edit a recipe's servings. Let's proceed ")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            modify_recipe()

        elif User_input == "quit":
            return

        else:
            print("\nThat is not a valid command, please try again with the commands allowed ")


def new_recipe():
    New_Recipe = input("Please enter the name of the new recipe you wish to add! ")
    Recipe_data = open(New_Recipe, 'w')
    Ingredients = input("Enter the number of ingredients ")
    Servings = input("Enter the servings required for this recipe ")

    for n in range (1,int(Ingredients)+1):

        Ingredient = input("Enter the name of the ingredient ")
        Recipe_data.write("\nIngrendient # " +str(n)+": \n")
        print("\n")
        Recipe_data.write(Ingredient)
        Recipe_data.write("\n")
        Quantities = input("Enter the quantity needed for this ingredient ")
        print("\n")
        Recipe_data.write(Quantities)
        Recipe_data.write("\n")

    for n in range (1,int(Ingredients)+1):
        Steps = input("\nEnter step " + str(n)+ ": ")
        print("\n")
        Recipe_data.write("\nStep " +str(n) + " is to: \n")
        Recipe_data.write("\n")
        Recipe_data.write(Steps)
    Recipe_data.close()

def exist_recipe():
    Choice_Exist= input("\nOkay, it looks like you want to view an existing recipe. Please enter the name of the recipe required. ")
    Exist_Recipe = open(Choice_Exist, "r+")
    print("\nThis recipe makes " + Choice_Exist)
    print(Exist_Recipe.read())
    time.sleep(1)

def modify_recipe():
    Choice_Exist = input("\nOkaym it looks like you want to modify a recipe. Please enter the name of this recipe ")
    Exist_Recipe = open(Choice_Exist, "r+")
    time.sleep(2)
    ServRequire = int(input("Please enter how many servings you would like "))


start()
```

**EDIT:** This is the new code, however I can still not figure out how to allow a user to multiply the original servings by entering how many servings are required, as the default servings are in a text file. Does anyone know how this can be done? I am new to file-handling and have been researching constantly but to no avail.

Comment: Hi @SpartanSK117, nicely laid out question. One small stylistic tip (not related to your specific question - variables in python (e.g. `New_Recipe`, `Ingredients`) should be all in lower case (e.g. `new_recipe`, `ingredients`). This is as specified in the python style guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: Thank you, surprisingly, my teacher is the one who said we should add a capital at the beginning of variables. I will change this now thanks! Also, do you have any suggestions on how I can rectify my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Python) How can I let a user open a text file and then change an integer / number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886107/python-how-can-i-let-a-user-open-a-text-file-and-then-change-an-integer-numb)

Comment: Currently you don't save `Servings` to the file in `new_recipe`. If you want to modify the quantities displayed for a different number of servings, you'll need this. Secondly, when you display an existing recipe, you just print the file - this is fine, but to modify the quantities you need to reverse what `new_recipe` did to write the file, so you get the values in variables you can modify before printing.

Answer (score 1):

For the number of people, you can get that from user input similar to how you got any other input in your code, with `num_people = input("How many people?")`.

Something a little more concerning you should look at. Your `start()` function calls its self. Unless you are using recursion, functions should not call themselves, it will build up on the stack. Use a while loop with something like

```
while ( 1 ):

    userinput = input("what would you like to do?")

    if( userinput == "n"):
            #new recipe

    ....

    if (user input == "quit"):
            sys.exit(1) #this will halt the program

    else:
          print "not valid input"
```

Comment: of coarse he would have to run for a long time to hit the recursion limit but yes good answwer

Comment: Thank you, I implemented something of this sort into my program. I've decided to re-write it to neaten it up and I've split the create a recipe, view a recipe and modify a recipe into three functions. I'll post back here when I 've fixed it (well most of it).

Answer (score 0):

You stored the whole data in a text file. This makes storage and retrieval easy, but makes changing values *real hard*. In these cases, you usually use ... well nevermind: you [asked the same question again and got a useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886107/python-how-can-i-let-a-user-open-a-text-file-and-then-change-an-integer-numb).

Comment: This is tagged with python 3, so there is no raw_input.

Comment: @matsjoyce: Thank you, that was correct.